# Localising with Wix 3.7 on VS2010

Tags: wix, installation

I'll start with that I haven't quite wrapped my head around the entire wix structure as yet, and still learning the basics.

But in trying an example to get localisation working, I've encountered an issue where it's thrown over 500 errors when trying to build.

I've practically followed this example, with the en-us codepage as default:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/make_installer_localizable.htm

I'll spare you the pain of all 546 errors, but here are the first few dozen.
Can anyone shed any light on what's happening?

> Error 12  The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlg_Title) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   13
>   Error 9   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgBannerBitmap) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   35
>   Error 3   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgComboLabel) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   23
>   Error 10  The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgDescription) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   38
>   Error 6   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolder) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   30
>   Error 7   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolderTooltip) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   30
>   Error 8   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgPathLabel) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   34
>   Error 11  The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgTitle) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   39
>   Error 4   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_Up) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   27
>   Error 5   The localization variable !(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_UpTooltip)
>   is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\BrowseDlg.wxs   27
>   Error 68  The localization variable !(loc.CancelDlg_Title) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\CancelDlg.wxs   13
>   Error 66  The localization variable !(loc.CancelDlgIcon) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\CancelDlg.wxs   21
>   Error 67  The localization variable !(loc.CancelDlgIconTooltip) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\CancelDlg.wxs   21
>   Error 65  The localization variable !(loc.CancelDlgText) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\CancelDlg.wxs   20
>   Error 19  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlg_Title) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 13
>   Error 14  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlgBannerBitmap) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 17
>   Error 16  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlgDescription) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 21
>   Error 15  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlgText) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 18
>   Error 17  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlgTitle) is unknown.
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 22
>   Error 18  The localization variable !(loc.DiskCostDlgVolumeList) is
>   unknown.  Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\DiskCostDlg.wxs 23
>   Error 386 The localization variable !(loc.Error0) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   85
>   Error 387 The localization variable !(loc.Error1) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   86
>   Error 394 The localization variable !(loc.Error10) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   95
>   Error 395 The localization variable !(loc.Error11) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   96
>   Error 410 The localization variable !(loc.Error1101) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   111
>   Error 396 The localization variable !(loc.Error12) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   97
>   Error 397 The localization variable !(loc.Error13) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   98
>   Error 411 The localization variable !(loc.Error1301) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   112
>   Error 412 The localization variable !(loc.Error1302) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   113
>   Error 413 The localization variable !(loc.Error1303) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   114
>   Error 414 The localization variable !(loc.Error1304) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   115
>   Error 415 The localization variable !(loc.Error1305) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   116
>   Error 416 The localization variable !(loc.Error1306) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   117
>   Error 417 The localization variable !(loc.Error1307) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   118
>   Error 418 The localization variable !(loc.Error1308) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   119
>   Error 419 The localization variable !(loc.Error1309) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   120
>   Error 420 The localization variable !(loc.Error1310) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   121
>   Error 421 The localization variable !(loc.Error1311) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   122
>   Error 422 The localization variable !(loc.Error1312) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   123
>   Error 423 The localization variable !(loc.Error1313) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   124
>   Error 424 The localization variable !(loc.Error1314) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   125
>   Error 425 The localization variable !(loc.Error1315) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   126
>   Error 426 The localization variable !(loc.Error1316) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   127
>   Error 427 The localization variable !(loc.Error1317) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   128
>   Error 428 The localization variable !(loc.Error1318) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   129
>   Error 429 The localization variable !(loc.Error1319) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   130
>   Error 430 The localization variable !(loc.Error1320) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   131
>   Error 431 The localization variable !(loc.Error1321) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   132
>   Error 432 The localization variable !(loc.Error1322) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   133
>   Error 433 The localization variable !(loc.Error1323) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   134
>   Error 434 The localization variable !(loc.Error1324) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   135
>   Error 435 The localization variable !(loc.Error1325) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   136
>   Error 436 The localization variable !(loc.Error1326) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   137
>   Error 437 The localization variable !(loc.Error1327) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   138
>   Error 438 The localization variable !(loc.Error1328) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   139
>   Error 439 The localization variable !(loc.Error1329) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   140
>   Error 440 The localization variable !(loc.Error1330) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   141
>   Error 441 The localization variable !(loc.Error1331) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   142
>   Error 442 The localization variable !(loc.Error1332) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   143
>   Error 443 The localization variable !(loc.Error1333) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   144
>   Error 444 The localization variable !(loc.Error1334) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   145
>   Error 445 The localization variable !(loc.Error1335) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   146
>   Error 446 The localization variable !(loc.Error1336) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   147
>   Error 398 The localization variable !(loc.Error14) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   99
>   Error 447 The localization variable !(loc.Error1401) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   148
>   Error 448 The localization variable !(loc.Error1402) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   149
>   Error 449 The localization variable !(loc.Error1403) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   150
>   Error 450 The localization variable !(loc.Error1404) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   151
>   Error 451 The localization variable !(loc.Error1405) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   152
>   Error 452 The localization variable !(loc.Error1406) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   153
>   Error 453 The localization variable !(loc.Error1407) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   154
>   Error 454 The localization variable !(loc.Error1408) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   155
>   Error 455 The localization variable !(loc.Error1409) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   156
>   Error 456 The localization variable !(loc.Error1410) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   157
>   Error 399 The localization variable !(loc.Error15) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   100
>   Error 457 The localization variable !(loc.Error1500) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   158
>   Error 458 The localization variable !(loc.Error1501) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   159
>   Error 459 The localization variable !(loc.Error1502) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   160
>   Error 460 The localization variable !(loc.Error1503) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   161
>   Error 400 The localization variable !(loc.Error16) is unknown.  Please
>   ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   101
>   Error 461 The localization variable !(loc.Error1601) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   162
>   Error 462 The localization variable !(loc.Error1602) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   163
>   Error 463 The localization variable !(loc.Error1603) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   164
>   Error 464 The localization variable !(loc.Error1604) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   165
>   Error 465 The localization variable !(loc.Error1605) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   166
>   Error 466 The localization variable !(loc.Error1606) is unknown. 
>   Please ensure the variable is
>   defined.  E:\delivery\Dev\wix37_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\ErrorProgressText.wxs   167

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the "Cultures to build" property.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/specifying_cultures_to_build.htm

Go to preferences of your setup project, build tab and fill in the "Cultures to build". This should help.

Comment: Well, though this wasn't the actual issue, it looks like this led me to the solution. By putting in 'en-US', the build compiled.
It appears, there isn't any localisation strings for one of the languages I added. en-AU. Australian. Which is totally absurb, as we all use English here.

Comment: @midspace Your culture should look like en-AU,en-US. This allows your culture to be Australian, but with fall back to default US, which mostly is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in such case is to add missing localization strings in your project. In my case I defined culture as pl-PL and got some missing localization strings like:

The localization variable !(loc.msierrXmlConfigFailedSelect) is unknown. Please ensure the variable is defined.
The localization variable !(loc.msierrXmlConfigFailedSave) is unknown. Please ensure the variable is defined.
etc.

I created a localization file with missing strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="pl-PL" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
<String Id="msierrXmlConfigFailedSelect">Zaznaczanie się nie powiodło, podczas edytowania XML.</String>
    <String Id="msierrXmlConfigFailedSave">Zapis się nie powiódł, podczas edytowania XML.</String>
    <String Id="msierrXmlConfigFailedRead">Odczyt się nie powiódł, podczas edytowania XML.</String>
    <String Id="msierrXmlConfigFailedOpen">Otwarcie pliku się nie powiodło, podczas edytowania XML.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```